# Fail with error 'Invalid amount of ether sent'

Tags: solidity, remix

I am trying to create a application to sell my ERC 20 Token. My token price is 0.0168 ETH and I am charging 3% as fee. I have created the smart contract an it worked in remix. I have now deployed it in goerli from hardhat. I get This error when I try to buy token from the front end.

My Contract :

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

import "./token.sol";

contract AeroSwap {
    address public admin;
    Token public token;
    uint public tokenPrice;
    uint public tokensSold;
    uint public feePercent;
    address public feeAddress;

    event Sell(address indexed _buyer, uint _amount);

    constructor(Token _token, uint _tokenPrice,uint _feePercent, address _feeAddress) {
        admin = msg.sender;
        token = _token;
        tokenPrice = _tokenPrice;
        feePercent = _feePercent;
        feeAddress = _feeAddress;
    }

    function buyTokens(uint _numberOfTokens) public payable {
        uint totalFee = (_numberOfTokens * feePercent)/100;
        uint totalAmount = (_numberOfTokens-totalFee)* tokenPrice;

        require(msg.value >= totalAmount, "Invalid amount of ether sent");
        require(token.balanceOf(address(this)) >= _numberOfTokens, "Insufficient tokens in contract");
        require(token.transfer(msg.sender, _numberOfTokens - totalFee), "Token transfer failed");
        require(token.transfer(feeAddress, totalFee),"Token transfer failed");
        tokensSold += _numberOfTokens - totalFee;
        emit Sell(msg.sender, _numberOfTokens-totalFee);
    }

    function endSale() public {
        require(msg.sender == admin, "Only admin can end sale");
        require(token.transfer(admin, token.balanceOf(address(this))), "Token transfer failed");
        payable(admin).transfer(address(this).balance);
        selfdestruct(payable(admin));
    }
}
```

My front end:

```
 import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Web3 from 'web3';
import TokenSwapABI from '../artifacts/contracts/token-swap.sol/AeroSwap.json';
import TokenAbi from '../artifacts/contracts/v2/Token.sol/Token.json';
import {ethers} from 'ethers';
import Web3Modal from 'web3modal';
import { tokenAddress, tokenSwapAddress } from '../config';

const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider);

export default function AeroSwap() {
  const [tokenPrice, setTokenPrice] = useState(null);
  const [tokensSold, setTokensSold] = useState(null);
  const [tokenAmount, setTokenAmount] = useState('');
  const [successMessage, setSuccessMessage] = useState(null);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState(null);
  const [successColor, setSuccessColor] = useState('green');
  const [errorColor, setErrorColor] = useState('red');
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(false)
  const [totalAmount, setTotalAmount]=useState();
  const contractAddress = aeroSwapAddress;
  const [feePercent, setFeePercent] = useState();
  

   
  useEffect(() => {
    getInitialInfo();
  }, []);

  useEffect(()=>{
    handleTotalAmount();
  },[tokenAmount])

  //getting information from contract
  const getInitialInfo=async()=>{
    const web3Modal = new Web3Modal();
    const connection = await web3Modal.connect();
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection);
    const signer = provider.getSigner();
    const tokenSwapContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, AeroSwapABI.abi, signer)
    
    tokenSwapContract.tokenPrice()
       .then(price => {
        setTokenPrice(ethers.utils.formatEther(price))
      });
    tokenSwapContract.tokensSold()
       .then(sold => setTokensSold(parseInt(sold, 16)));
    tokenSwapContract.feePercent()
    .then(feePercent =>{ 
      setFeePercent(feePercent.toString())})
  }
  
  //handle token buying 
  const handleBuyToken = async()=> {
    const web3Modal = new Web3Modal();
    const connection = await web3Modal.connect();
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection);
    const signer = provider.getSigner();
    await window.ethereum.enable();

    const tokenSwapcontract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, TokenSwapABI.abi, signer)

    const tokenAddress = tokenAddress;
    const token = new ethers.Contract(tokenAddress, TokenAbi.abi, signer);
    if(tokenAmount == '' || tokenAmount == undefined){
      setErrorMessage('Please enter the number of Tokens.');
    }else{
      const totalfee = (tokenAmount * feePercent)/100;
      const tokenAmountinNum = Number(tokenAmount)
      const tokenPriceinNum = Number(tokenPrice)
      const totalAmount = (tokenAmountinNum + totalfee)*tokenPriceinNum
      const ttlAmt =ethers.utils.parseEther(String(totalAmount))
      console.log("totalAmoun",totalAmount)
      const tokAmt = ethers.utils.parseEther(String(tokenAmount))
      console.log("tokAmt",tokAmt)
      try{
        const gasPrice = await provider.getGasPrice();
         
       const tx = await aeroSwapcontract.buyTokens(tokAmt,{
        value: ttlAmt ,
        gasPrice: gasPrice,
        gasLimit: 5000000
      });
        
        await tx.wait();
        setSuccessMessage('Transaction successful!');
      }
      catch(error){
           console.log(error);
           setErrorMessage('Transaction failed. Please try again.');
      }
    
  }
    
  };

  //runs when the token Amount changes
  const handleTotalAmount=async(e)=>{

    const web3Modal = new Web3Modal();
    const connection = await web3Modal.connect();
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection);

    const gasPrice = await provider.getGasPrice();
    const gas = ethers.utils.formatEther( gasPrice.toNumber())
    const totalfee = (tokenAmount * feePercent)/100;
      const tokenAmountinNum = Number(tokenAmount)
      const tokenPriceinNum = Number(tokenPrice)
      const totalAmount = (((tokenAmountinNum + totalfee)*tokenPriceinNum)+Number(gas)).toFixed(6)
      if(tokenAmount == ''||tokenAmount == undefined){
        setTotalAmount(0.00000)
      }else{
        setTotalAmount(totalAmount)
      }
     
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="flex justify-center">
        <div className="w-1/2 flex flex-col pb-12">
          <h1
            className="py-10 text-3xl flex "
            style={{ color: "#3079AB", alignSelf: "flex-start" }}
          >
            Buy Tokens
          </h1>
          <p className="rounded mt-4 font-bold">1ETH = 100 token</p>
          <p className="rounded mt-4 font-bold">Token Price: ${tokenPrice}</p>
          <p className="rounded mt-4 font-bold">Tokens Sold: {tokensSold}</p>
          <p className="rounded mt-4 font-bold">Fee Percent: {feePercent}%</p>
          <input value={tokenAmount} className="mt-2 border rounded p-4" placeholder="Number of Aero coins" onChange={(e)=>setTokenAmount(e.target.value)} />
          <p>Your total value: {totalAmount}</p>
          <button className="font-bold text-white rounded p-4 shadow-lg" style={{ backgroundColor: "#3079AB",marginTop: "2%"}} onClick={handleBuyToken}>Buy Tokens</button>
          <div className="w-1/2 flex flex-col pb-12" style={{marginTop: "2%"}}>
            {successMessage && (
              <p style={{ color: successColor }}>{successMessage}</p>
            )}
            {errorMessage && (
              <p style={{ color: errorColor }}>{errorMessage}</p>
            )}
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

It fails when I try to do the transaction from the front end.

Input :

```
amountInBigNUm BigNumber {_hex: '0x39e5202b427ffe', _isBigNumber: true} aak-swap.js?7a6c:70 tokenAmt BigNumber {_hex: '0x0de0b6b3a7640000', _isBigNumber: true} aak-swap.js?7a6c:73 gas Price BigNumber {_hex: '0x3299a7bb64', _isBigNumber: true}
```

Error : Fail with error 'Invalid amount of ether sent'

Comment: What values did you use for `_tokenPrice`, `_feePercent`? And for `_numberOfTokens`?

Comment: _tokenPrice is 0.0168 ETH and _feePercent 3% and _numberOfTokens is 1. I am passing the value in bigNumber

Comment: Is `_numberOfTokens` just 1 or `10^18`?

Comment: Please look at the update

Comment: Following the javascript `feePercent` should be a string. Can you log the intermediate values of `totalfee`, `totalAmount`. I don't understand why in the contract you take the fee from the `_numberOfTokens`. In any case I'd suggest to write unit test for your token and swap contract.

Comment: Yes I was using string I corrected it but still the same error